# Why overriding a method of superclass, instead of giving it a different name?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I have the following code example:

```
class Primate {
   public void sayType() {
      System.out.println("I'm a Primate");
   }
}

class Human extends Primate {
   public void sayType() {
      System.out.println("I'm a Human!");
   }
}
public class TalkingPrimates {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Primate a = new Primate();
      Primate b = new Human();

      a.sayType(); 
      b.sayType(); 
   }
}
```

which should output:

```
I'm a Primate
I'm a Human!
```

Why can't I just name the `sayType` method to `humanHello` for example, and avoid messing with `@Override` and confusing later? I'm a newbie, and taken this example somewhere else, so maybe there are more complicated usages for it that you will show me

(Another thing - the line `Primate b = new Human()`, is it what called "Dynamic method dispatch"?)

Comment: This is called "Polymorphism". You should read about it. It's one of the important features of object-oriented programming.

Comment: The usefulness of this type of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) is that you can write code that calls `primate.sayType()` without knowing its run-time type, and get the correct implementation of that function.

Comment: Why using Java if you are not interested in polymorphism?

Comment: If you just name `sayType` method to `humanHello`, you have to remember yourself to invoke that new method. So, the `b.sayType();` will be updated to `b.humanHello(); `What happen if you have 5 or 6 such new methods, how we can remember each method name need to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do as you say then you could not take advantage of Polymorphism e.g.

```
for(Primate p : primateList){
  p.sayType(); // 
}
```

With that you can let the Objects do the implementation of your pre-defined method name and be sure that it's always the same name.

Comment: Thank you! I mentioned I'm a newbie (with no idea about Polymorphism), but now that you've mentioned it, I've looked at a few tutorials and I understand it better now!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could, but then `Primate b = new Human(); b.sayType();` would output "I'm a primate". Furthermore, you would not be able to access `humanHello` via a reference to a `Primate`, unless you took a nasty reference cast, which would fail if the reference was not referring to a `Human` instance.

Overriding is useful if you have a container of references to primates (humans, gibbons, etc.), and you want to access the correct method through a particular reference.